# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a folder inside my asp.net solution named admin. I have created few pages inside it like categories.aspx, users.aspx. I uploaded code to my hosting and when i try to access it using:

```
www.mydomain/admin/
```

I get:

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

I looks like that hosting is looking for default.aspx inside this folder. How can I make users.aspx as default page for this folder ?

Please suggest.

Comment: Change the setting in IIS. You can also set the permission for directory listing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suppose that you're using IIS7 or greater.

If you have access to IIS configurations you can do it direclty there, if not, you could add a default page using web.config

You'll need to create specific web.config on folder `/admin/` containing only default page settings.

[Here](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument) you have all the details about how to do it on IIS and how to do it on web.config

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to IIS and add 'User.aspx' as a 'default page' to www.mydomain.com.